# Is it possible to prohibit users from deleting files from Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

I'm an administrator for my organization and I got a report that someone deleted a file that was shared with other users. The original owner deleted the file (or caused it's deletion somehow) and now both the user and the file are nowhere to be found.

When removing users, we *always* transfer their files to a manager-user to preserve whatever work they had done.

We'd like to prevent users from intentionally or unintentionally deleting files from Google Drive. Is this possible? It seems like a required feature for businesses where document-preservation is a legal requirement.

Comment: Google drive is imho not a solution to share files. I would suggest that you take a look at remote desktop as you could be more restricted. and afaik no its not possible, but you can also use the Google support to clarify the situation

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [Google Vault](https://workspace.google.com/products/vault/)'s [retention feature](https://support.google.com/vault/answer/2990828?hl=en&ref_topic=3209998) for that. Vault has an explicit feature for legal holds, but you can also use it to enforce removal or long term storage of files & emails.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, I think this requires Google Workspace Business or Enterprise subscriptions, and I only have "Business Starter". Searching for "Vault" in the settings finds a configuration-page in the search results, but choosing it from those search-results returns a 404 Not Found response. :(